# Instance Switching

Tags: performance, instance

Has anyone had experience in requesting a Salesforce org be migrated from a different geographic instance to another?

Our org was setup a number of years ago (10+) by someone in our US office. Our US office is around 4 staff members. Our EU office has over 100 members of staff. As per the [Improve performance and speed in Lightning Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000250291&language=en_US&type=1) recommendations from Salesforce, it looks like it might be worth me asking them to move our org from a NA instance to an EU instance to improve performance for our primary user base.

Has anyone successfully managed to do/request this in the past? Is it best to go via support or our account manager?

Comment: While I haven't really seen or known about instance switches, but going through Account Manager will get you faster response (based on my experiences on SLA for other critical issues).